# How to create an error_log in each's vhosts httpdocs directory

Tags: logging, centos6, virtualhost

Running a CentOS 6.4 server with Plesk 11 and virtual hosts for each client/domain.

What I'm now trying to accomplish is to auto-create an error_log in each user's httpdocs folder in case of problems with the script running in this directory.

Someone who know how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to do work for you, but rather to help you solve problems based on issues you are having & solutions you have tried.

Comment: @JakeGould I've just tried nothing yet because I haven't found any source to get started with. I found an apache source about creating error logs and virtual hosts but I'm not sure this is the right thing since it says that each virtual host needs its own IP adress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to. Plesk is already configured to create error_logs for every domain. You can find them at `/var/www/vhosts/<domainname>/statistics/logs/`

Comment: @etangenklo Generally you are right, so I marked your answer as the correct answer. However, if you read my question carefully again, I was asking to put an error_log into the httpdocs folder and only with errors of the script running in this folder, in example php fatal errors or other developing errors. In case if you know a solution for this as well, would be nice if you will update your answer. Thanks.